# V-for vue.js data

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Hi am trying  to show all array that i have 
with this example i can show only the first line because [0]
i wanna show all

```
<div class="description" v-for="item in sitePartVoice[0].part_attributes">
<small><strong>{{item.x_name}}</strong> {{item.x_value}}</small>
</div>
```

i have try this

```
<div v-for="item in items">
 <div class="description" v-for="item in sitePartVoice.part_attributes">
    <small><strong>{{item.x_name}}</strong> {{item.x_value}}</small>
    </div>
</div>
```

No Success
thanks

Comment: Can you show what your data looks like? It seems to me like `sitePartVoice` is an array so you can't get `part_attributes` directly.

Comment: I'm guessing it would be something like `v-for="part in sitePartVoice"` on the outer div and then `v-for="item in part.part_attributes"` on the inner div

Comment: what is your data array looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be like

```
<div v-for="siteParts in sitePartVoice">
 <div class="description" v-for="item in siteParts.part_attributes">
    <small><strong>{{item.x_name}}</strong> {{item.x_value}}</small>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have this kind of data:

```js
    data: () => ({
      sitePartVoice: [
        { 
            part_attributes: [
                {
                    prop1: 'value1'
                }
            ] 
        },
        { 
            part_attributes: [
                {
                    prop1: 'value1'
                }
            ] 
        }
      ]
    })
```

then to loop each `sitePartVoice` and loop the `part_attributes` inside it:

```
        <div v-for="item in sitePartVoice">
            <div class="description" v-for="i in item.part_attributes">
                <small>{{i.prop1}}</small>
            </div>
        </div>
```